# AnimateWindow API hide leaves trails

Tags: c++, winapi, animatewindow

I am using `AnimateWindow` to show/hide my toolbar. During Hide the toolbar leaves a trail and after a few seconds it disappears. How can I eliminate these trails during hide?

```
AnimateWindow(m_hWndToolbar, 200,  AW_SLIDE | AW_VER_NEGATIVE | AW_HIDE);
ShowWindow(m_hWndToolbar, SW_HIDE);
```

[Trails image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6RDJ.jpg)

Comment: Remove the Animation.  _"...To show or hide a window without special effects, use ShowWindow...."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-animatewindow

Comment: Yes I can remove it, but it will not meet the animation requirement  during hide event.  How can I meet the requirement but not  have the trail issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The trail is part of the the Animation

Comment: `AnimateWindow` doesn't appear to have aged well. Indeed, I don't even recall the last time I witnessed it working as advertised. See if the DWM provides an alternative that actually works.